# application content goes behind the navigation bar in android L

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

[image]

As you can see my "Got It" button is behind the navigation bar.Not able to fix it!!! I have tried

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

As well as setting it in layout file.

my theme in value-21 is :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    </style>
```

Its the same case with all the screens throughout the application.

Please Help.

Comment: Try : View.bringToFront();

Comment: @user863873:layout should not use this space.It should be above these buttons.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is the solution.

Most of the layouts get solved by adding these properties in values-v21 style.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

for others, I have calculated the hight of navigation bar and add margin to my view .

```
public static int getSoftButtonsBarSizePort(Activity activity) {
    // getRealMetrics is only available with API 17 and +
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
        int realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        if (realHeight > usableHeight)
            return realHeight - usableHeight;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:**  By using the above solutions everything work but I was also using PopupWindow in my app.The layout of the PopupWindow get messed up in android L. Look for the issue and the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340878/popup-window-is-not-properly-shown-in-android-l)

Comment: I added the following to my style
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>

It works! No content is being drawn behind the navigation bar. Except now my navigation bar is a dark gray instead of black. Putting TranslucentNavigation to false makes the bar black, but content draws behind it. Think you could explain why these attributes work, and how to keep the navigation bar black?

Comment: You have defined the method but you did not tell us how to use it or calling it. Can you kindly tell us where to call that method from and how to use what its returning.

Answer (score 7):

It is so simple, 
just add this line to your parent layout xml:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: Not working on pie may be it's not working since android M

Answer (score 6):

For nice user experience you should not need to block navigation keys area using `android:windowTranslucentNavigation`

rather here is the better solution, if you are using ResideMenu library then simply add this method in ResideMenu.java

```
  @Override
protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {
    int bottomPadding = insets.bottom;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            bottomPadding += resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
    }
    this.setPadding(viewActivity.getPaddingLeft() + insets.left, viewActivity.getPaddingTop() + insets.top,
            viewActivity.getPaddingRight() + insets.right, viewActivity.getPaddingBottom() + bottomPadding);
    insets.left = insets.top = insets.right = insets.bottom = 0;
    return true;
}
```

and if you are using `SlidingMenu` library then change mod to `SLIDING_CONTENT` by:

```
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
```

Hope it will save your time

Answer (score 4):

Simply set this in your Activity's onCreate(), while setting up content view :

```
int mScreenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int mScreenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
setContentView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in your onCreate method of your `Activity`(If you have `BaseActivity` you can do this there so all activities apply this):

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(
            findViewById(android.R.id.content), (v, insets) -> {
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                params.bottomMargin = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
                return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
            });
```

When a layout has this flag, it means that this layout is asking the system to be applied window insets. In our case that would mean, that FrameLayout desires to be applied a padding that is equal to status bar’s height.

Comment: For pre-lambda:
        `.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener (findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
                        
// ..
                    }
                }
        );`

Answer (score 1):

I tried many answers above, but none of them worked for me. I have wrapped my relative layout in which my button (which has to be attached to bottom) in another linear layout. It worked for me magically.

If someone can add the reason for this, it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases and by **default**, the navigation bar should always be **below** the app unless you've triggered a setting.

If that's the behavior you want to make sure you're not running this line:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `softInputMode` of `popupWindow` to `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before setcontent view of your java, My problem got solved by this`

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`
```