# add layout to scrollable navigation view footer android

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

How to add custom layout to scrollable navigation view footer?

i've tried extend navigationView to ListView, but it seems didn't work for design support 23+

i've tried add view inside navigation view, but it works only for static navigationView (un-scrollable navigationView)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30705784/3737254

i've tried nested navigationView, it seems didn't work 
(http://blog.nitish.io/post/122633295558/android-design-library-navigationview-with-footer)

any clues / helps?

thanks

Comment: you better extend RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792887/android-navigationview-displays-under-navigationbar-and-cannot-click-how-to-so/34793614#34793614

Comment: just wondering there is no way to inflate view to the bottom of navigationview? @mehrdadkhosravi