# Android Sliding Tabs cuts off Fragments and FAB not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I have two questions/problems :)

First: I have implemented a Sliding Tabs Layout. Now the fragment is use for the Tabs get cut off at the bottom:
[Fragment gets cut off (FAB is on bottom|right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjs3G.png)

Second: When I press the FAB i want to open a new Activity (the FAB is on a Fragment). But when I press it, a blank Activity opens (the acctual Activity has a Layout and is working on its own) and when I press the back button I exit the app.

For the First question: This is a Methode I call in the onCreate of the MainActivity (Where the Sliding Tabs Layout is implemented) (I dont know if you need the code for the ViewPager so I didn't include it, if you need it tell me please):

```
 private void excTasks(){
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}
```

This is the ViewPagerAdapter:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        //return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);

        // Wenn man nur Icons will -> return null, sont das obrige verwenden
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here I add the Fragments:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new NewsFragment(), "NEWS");
    adapter.addFragment(new ProfileFragment(), "PROFILE");
    adapter.addFragment(new NotificationFragment(), "NOTIF");
    adapter.addFragment(new AboutFragment(), "ABOUT");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is the .xml of the MainActivity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For the second question: 
This is in the Fragment (in the onViewCreated) where I want the FAB (OfferActivity is what should be opened when pressing the button):

```
//FAB
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Click action
            Intent intent = new Intent(con, OfferActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

As said before, the OfferActivity is working fine when displayed in one Tab, so I won't include the code of it.
Here is the FAB xml (inside a RelativeLayout): EDIT: included the whole file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="fill"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_add"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Thank you for answering and sorry if this questions got ask already! :)

EDIT: here is the styles.xml and I have included the whole FAB xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>-->
</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can you please post your style.xml

Comment: Please post the complete xml in which Floating action button is included

Comment: I don't see the tab been included inside the pager. for example <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>. see http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Avi, why I didnt include them because I get the toolbar and tabselector bar  from the MainActivity. If I include them I have 2 of them. :)

Answer (score 1):

The use of `layout_baselineAlignBottom` attribute is creating problem I think. The `app:layout_anchor` attribute enables us to specify the layout on which we wish to anchor our floating action button & `app:layout_anchorGravity` specifies the placement of the anchor. Place the following floating action button xml at the end just before `</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/fab"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
   android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
   android:src="@drawable/fab_add"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
   android:clickable="true"
   app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"   
   app:layout_anchor="@id/viewpager"
   app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"  />
```

Please note: Floating  Action button can only be used in conjunction with Coordinator layout.

Edit: Okay, wrap your Relative layout inside a coordinator layout, and change
`app:layout_anchor="@id/viewpager"` to `app:layout_anchor="@id/listview"` in floating action button xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="fill"/>


</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/list"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_add"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I tried it, but now the FAB is floating below the last feed item, half overlapping it. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/103t3LO)

Comment: Where do you want the FAB to be exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use that `FloatingActionButton` with `CoordinatorLayout` like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppbarLayout/>
    <scrollableView/>
    <FloatingActionButton/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Something like this(you can use SupportLibrary or using it inside the `CoordinatorLayout`) this is the best way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/ColorAccent"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/coordinator"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but here I get the same problem as with Abdullah's solution, the FAB is floating below the last feed item, half overlapping it.

Comment: What are the codes? perhaps your contents has a problem.otherwise, this is the standrad way.

Answer (score 0):

Hope something got messed up with the value-v21 style.xml.

Try adding the below set of properties in the value-v21 style.xml.

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

and add the below code to the fab fragment.

```
private int getNavigationBarHeight() { 
    Resources resources = getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    } 
    return 0; 
} 

@Override 
public void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        int navBarHeight = getNavigationBarHeight();
        findViewById(R.id.base_frame).setPadding(0, 0, 0, navBarHeight);
        findViewById(R.id.menu_frame).setPadding(0, 0, 0, navBarHeight);
    } 
}
```

Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303342/application-content-goes-behind-the-navigation-bar-in-android-l)

Good Luck..!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What exactly are the base_frame and menu_frame views (since I don't know what to set the padding :))?

Comment: But this is not right way to add padding i did exactly It works fine for nexus but in some devices i am getting extra margin from bottom. Do you are solution related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
public class DeliveryTab extends Fragment {
    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    View view;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle("Delivery");

        View x =  inflater.inflate(com.Weal.sachin.omcom.R.layout.activity_delivery_tab,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(com.Weal.sachin.omcom.R.id.sliding_tabs_delivery);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(com.Weal.sachin.omcom.R.id.viewpager_delivery);
        viewPager. setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)x.findViewById(R.id.fabdelivery);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Add_Delivery mFrag = new Add_Delivery();
                t.replace(R.id.framelayout, mFrag);
                t.commit();
            }
        });
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        return x;

    }
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        com.Weal.sachin.omcom.TodayVisit TodayVisit;
        Home home;
        com.Weal.sachin.omcom.UpdatesFragment UpdatesFragment;
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new DeliveryToday();
                case 1 : return new YesterdayDelivery();
                case 2 : return new Delivery_all();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Today";
                case 1 :
                    return "Yesterday";
                case 2 :
                    return "Delivery All";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Here the xml :-

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.Weal.sachin.omcom.TabFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs_delivery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:tabTextColor="#d2cece"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
        android:background="#11977c"

        />
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_delivery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <fragment android:name="com.Weal.sachin.omcom.TabFragment"
            android:id="@+id/tabFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabdelivery"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="124dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:backgroundTint="#11977c"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/addplus"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the floatingaction bar remains in the tab and its works good for me.