# layout_alignParentBottom to LinearLayout not showing in screen

Tags: android, xml

I am making form in my application in fragment. My parent view is RelativeLayout and in that i have ScrollView and Linearlayout. Scrollview contails form and LinearLayout contains Buttons to submit form. Preview screen shows properly in Android Studio. But after debugging it Button's Linearlayout is not display inside screen.

[image: Screen]

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".LeaveCreate">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="Duration"
                android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtFromDate"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:hint="From"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtToDate"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:hint="To"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/calender"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:text="Teacher"
                android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.example.acg.digimkeyparent.MultiSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/teacherSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">
                </com.example.acg.digimkeyparent.MultiSpinner>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:text="Reason"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtReason"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start|top"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:minLines="5"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnFileSelect"
                        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                        android:text="Attach"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/attach"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/attach"
                        android:textColor="@color/appdefault"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                        android:text="Send"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/send"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/send"
                        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

And My 2nd Question is My selected tab is not highlighted after use Customize View.

```
public class LeaveApplication extends AppCompatActivity implements LeaveCreate.OnFragmentInteractionListener,LeaveHistory.OnFragmentInteractionListener{


private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave_application);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

    TextView newTab = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    newTab.setText("Create"); //tab label txt
    ImageView im1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
    im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.create_icon);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(v);

    View v1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

    TextView newTab1 = (TextView)  v1.findViewById(R.id.text);
    newTab1.setText("Leave History"); //tab label txt
    ImageView im2 = (ImageView) v1.findViewById(R.id.image);
    im2.setImageResource(R.drawable.view_icon);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(v1);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i,true);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicator(R.color.md_white_1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
  /*
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_leave_create, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
 */
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new LeaveCreate();
            case 1:
                return new LeaveHistory();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try setting android:fitsSystemWindows to true on your parent layout .. this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303342/application-content-goes-behind-the-navigation-bar-in-android-l

Answer (score 0):

Please provide an "id" to the **linear layout of your buttons**.
For example:  android:id="@+id/linear"
Then in **scroll view**,
    _android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/linear"
    is added.

For **highlighting the selected tab**, you can try:
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(//color you want to use)

Comment: no still no change in both. Check i edited code in question.

Comment: Did you check adding android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  to the buttons?

Comment: Also setTabTextColors(int,int) can help to show normal and selected text colors

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="bottom"` to LinearLayout containing buttons.

To select the tab try

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
tab.select();

tabLayout.setTabTextColors([Normal color], [Selected color]);
```