# How To Create Activity Over Home Button

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I want to create an activity over home button on phone. 
In some devices home button overlay activity.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean navigation bar and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303342/application-content-goes-behind-the-navigation-bar-in-android-l) question, the solution would be adding these properties in value-21 `style.xml` :

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

another way would be:

```
public static int getSoftButtonsBarSizePort(Activity activity) {
// getRealMetrics is only available with API 17 and +
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
    int realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    if (realHeight > usableHeight)
        return realHeight - usableHeight;
    else
        return 0;
}
return 0;
```

}